# How do I determine the relative length of an object based of travel time?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let me put this question into a problem:

> Train A passes a milestone in 8 seconds before meeting train B. The two trains pass each other in  9 seconds. Then train B passes the same milestone in 12 seconds. Train A and B are traveling at equal speeds. Which of the following statements about the length of the trains is true?

The options are:

- Train A is twice as long as Train B
- Train B is twice as long as Train A
- They are of equal length
- B is 50% longer than A
- A is 50% longer than B

I would like to know how to determine the relative length of objects based on travel time.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried drawing a diagram?

Comment: I have but it didn't make sense and I was unable to determine their lengths.

Comment: Shouldn't it take $10$ seconds for them to pass one another?  Where does this problem come from?

Comment: This comes from a math competition question. I can send attach a pdf clip to the question.

Comment: You probably should post a link to the image, perhaps in a comment. The exact wording is vitally important here; for example, if either occurrence of the word "in" after "milestone" is not in the original problem statement, it changes the meaning completely.

Comment: No PDF yet. I'm disappointed. I was curious to see how we might resolve this question.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the distance traveled at constant speed is equal to the rate of speed times the time.  Suppose train A is $a$ feet long, and train B is $b$ feet long, and that both trains travel at $f$ feet per second.

It takes $8$ seconds for train A to pass a point.  In those $8$ seconds, the train traveled $8f$ feet, so $a=8f.$  Similarly, $b=12f$, and the the fourth choice is correct.

B is $50\%$ longer than A.

I don't understand how they can say it takes $9$ seconds for the trains to pass one another.  Say the trains pass each other in $t$ seconds.  In that time each trains has advanced $ft$ feet, so the fronts of the two trains are $2ft$ feet apart.  But the distance between the fronts is equal to the sum of the length of the trains, which is $20f,$ and so $t=10.$

The time it takes for the two trains to pass one another is a red herring, as is the fact that train B passes the milestone $12$ seconds later.  I guess the problem author was just careless.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is:

- B is 50% longer than A.

**The information "The two trains pass each other in 9 seconds" is not important, it is superfluous.**

Important is only the time during which trains pass the milestone:

- Train A passes the milestone in 8 seconds.
- Train B passes the milestone in 12 seconds.

So train B is 50% longer than train A.

---

*Note:*

From the passenger point of view the train is *stationary*, and the milestone is *moving in opposite direction* to meet the train. So the milestone moves along a longer train during longer time.

Comment: I checked the answer key. The correct answer is A is twice as long as B. I believe that you may have misunderstood some parts of the question.

Comment: For now there are 3 answers to your question, and no one agree with your "correct" answer. I know, it's not a proof, but something is wrong. With formulation of that problem, or the "correct" answer is not correct.

Comment: I've tried several different ways to parse the problem with slight changes in wording but the same numbers, and none of them is even close to compatible with the "correct" answer. I think we really need to see the photo of the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_A$ and $L_B$ be the lengths of trains $A$ and $B$, respectively. Let $w$ be the width of the mile stone and $v$ be the speed of the two trains. From the milestone equations we get $$v=\frac{L_A+w}{8}\implies 8v=L_A+w$$ $$v=\frac{L_B+w}{12}\implies 12v=L_B+w$$ $$2v=\frac{L_A+L_B}{9}\implies 18v=L_A+L_B$$

Subtracting the first equation from the second gives $$4v=L_B-L_A$$

Adding this to the third equation gives $$22v=2L_B\implies 11v=L_B$$ and substituting back into the previous equation gives us $L_A=7v$.

Therefore, $L_B=\frac{11}{7}L_A$.

Comment: So $w = \frac17 L_A = \frac1{11} L_B.$ Interesting interpretation; on reading the problem, I assumed the milestone had no width (that is, $w=0$) but this resolves the contradiction in the problem statement. Too bad the problem's author did not think of this and offer $L_B = \frac{11}7 L_A$ as a possible answer.